# Azure AD B2C: How to reference built in claims in custom policies?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am writing a custom policy for AAD B2C and need to include some built-in claims (country/region, postalcode, city, address).

I've used the starter pack and noticed that even claims like e-mail are declared in the schema on TrustFrameworkBase ClaimSchema element like the sample below, some of them references a DefaultPartnerClaimTypes element by protocol:

```
<ClaimsSchema>
...

  <ClaimType Id="displayName">
        <DisplayName>Display Name</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
          <Protocol Name="OAuth2" PartnerClaimType="unique_name" />
          <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="name" />
          <Protocol Name="SAML2" PartnerClaimType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" />
        </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
        <UserHelpText>Your display name.</UserHelpText>
        <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
      </ClaimType>
...
      <ClaimType Id="email">
        <DisplayName>Email Address</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
          <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="email" />
        </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
        <Restriction>
          <Pattern RegularExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&amp;'^_`{}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$" HelpText="Please enter a valid email address." />
        </Restriction>
      </ClaimType>
...
</ClaimsSchema>
```

These are text typed claims and the e-mail claim for instance has a regex restriction to validate email adress, my question is regarding a country/region claims for example, which in the built in claim are enumeration restricted and presented as dropdown. Is it possible to reference it from my custom policy without defining all elements and rules? Simply reference the built-in ClaimType?

Thank you

Comment: Hi Alex, I meet the same problem as you. So what is your final decision? I also want to reuse the build-in claims contry/region in custom policy.  But I don't want to list all the countries in <Restriction /> element in custom policy, do you find some other approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **country** claim is mapped to the **country** property of [the **user** object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity). The **country** property of a **user** object can contain any string value.

So it's up to the policy developer to determine if the **country** claim should be limited to a well-known list of values or not.

If so, then you must add [the `<Restriction />` element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claimsschema#dropdownsingleselect) to the claim type.

Comment: Thank you for the response! So, I undesrstand that if I am to limit the values the same way it already is in the built-in claim I must delcar the restriction list, is not possible to reuse the claim definition from the built-in claims. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the countryCode claim from [this example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/scenarios/phone-number-passwordless/Phone_Email_Base.xml).

```
<ClaimType Id="countryCode">
    <DisplayName>Country</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <UserHelpText>Enter Country</UserHelpText>
    <UserInputType>DropdownSingleSelect</UserInputType>
    <Restriction>
      <Enumeration Text="Albania(+355)" Value="AL" />
      <Enumeration Text="Algeria(+213)" Value="DZ" />
      <Enumeration Text="American Samoa(+1684)" Value="AS" />
      <Enumeration Text="Andorra(+376)" Value="AD" />
      <Enumeration Text="Angola(+244)" Value="AO" />
      <Enumeration Text="Anguilla(+1264)" Value="AI" />
      <Enumeration Text="Antarctica(+672)" Value="AQ" />
      <Enumeration Text="Antigua and Barbuda(+1268)" Value="AG" />
      <Enumeration Text="Argentina(+54)" Value="AR" />
      <Enumeration Text="Armenia(+374)" Value="AM" />
      <Enumeration Text="Aruba(+297)" Value="AW" />
      <Enumeration Text="Australia(+61)" Value="AU" />
      <Enumeration Text="Austria(+43)" Value="AT" />
      <Enumeration Text="Azerbaijan(+994)" Value="AZ" />
      <Enumeration Text="Bahamas(+1242)" Value="BS" />
      <Enumeration Text="Bahrain(+973)" Value="BH" />
      <Enumeration Text="Bangladesh(+880)" Value="BD" />
      <Enumeration Text="Barbados(+1246)" Value="BB" />
      <Enumeration Text="Belarus(+375)" Value="BY" />
      <Enumeration Text="Belgium(+32)" Value="BE" />
      <Enumeration Text="Belize(+501)" Value="BZ" />
      <Enumeration Text="Benin(+229)" Value="BJ" />
      <Enumeration Text="Bermuda(+1441)" Value="BM" />
      <Enumeration Text="Bhutan(+975)" Value="BT" />
      <Enumeration Text="Bolivia(+591)" Value="BO" />
      <Enumeration Text="Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba(+599)" Value="BQ" />
      <Enumeration Text="Bosnia and Herzegovina(+387)" Value="BA" />
      <Enumeration Text="Botswana(+267)" Value="BW" />
      <Enumeration Text="Brazil(+55)" Value="BR" />
      <Enumeration Text="British Virgin Islands (+1284)" Value="VG" />
      <Enumeration Text="Brunei Darussalam(+673)" Value="BN" />
      <Enumeration Text="Bulgaria(+359)" Value="BG" />
      <Enumeration Text="Burkina Faso(+226)" Value="BF" />
      <Enumeration Text="Burundi(+257)" Value="BI" />
      <Enumeration Text="Cambodia(+855)" Value="KH" />
      <Enumeration Text="Cameroon(+237)" Value="CM" />
      <Enumeration Text="Canada(+1)" Value="CA" />
      <Enumeration Text="Cape Verde(+238)" Value="CV" />
      <Enumeration Text="Cayman Islands(+1345)" Value="KY" />
      <Enumeration Text="Central African Republic(+236)" Value="CF" />
      <Enumeration Text="Chad(+235)" Value="TD" />
      <Enumeration Text="Chile(+56)" Value="CL" />
      <Enumeration Text="China(+86)" Value="CN" />
      <Enumeration Text="Colombia(+57)" Value="CO" />
      <Enumeration Text="Comoros(+269)" Value="KM" />
      <Enumeration Text="Congo(+242)" Value="CG" />
      <Enumeration Text="Cook Islands(+682)" Value="CK" />
      <Enumeration Text="Costa Rica(+506)" Value="CR" />
      <Enumeration Text="Côte d'Ivoire(+225)" Value="CI" />
      <Enumeration Text="Croatia(+385)" Value="HR" />
      <Enumeration Text="Cuba(+53)" Value="CU" />
      <Enumeration Text="Curaçao(+599)" Value="CZ" />
      <Enumeration Text="Cyprus(+357)" Value="CW" />
      <Enumeration Text="Czech Republic(+420)" Value="CZ" />
      <Enumeration Text="Congo (+243)" Value="CD" />
      <Enumeration Text="Denmark(+45)" Value="DK" />
      <Enumeration Text="Djibouti(+253)" Value="DJ" />
      <Enumeration Text="Dominica(+1767)" Value="DM" />
      <Enumeration Text="Dominican Republic(+1)" Value="DO" />
      <Enumeration Text="Timor-Leste(+670)" Value="TL" />
      <Enumeration Text="Ecuador(+593)" Value="EC" />
      <Enumeration Text="Egypt(+20)" Value="EG" />
      <Enumeration Text="El Salvador(+503)" Value="SV" />
      <Enumeration Text="Equatorial Guinea(+240)" Value="GQ" />
      <Enumeration Text="Eritrea(+291)" Value="ER" />
      <Enumeration Text="Estonia(+372)" Value="EE" />
      <Enumeration Text="Ethiopia(+251)" Value="ET" />
      <Enumeration Text="Falkland Islands (Malvinas)(+500)" Value="FK" />
      <Enumeration Text="Faroe Islands(+298)" Value="FO" />
      <Enumeration Text="Fiji(+679)" Value="FJ" />
      <Enumeration Text="Finland(+358)" Value="FI" />
      <Enumeration Text="France(+33)" Value="FR" />
      <Enumeration Text="French Guiana(+594)" Value="GF" />
      <Enumeration Text="French Polynesia(+689)" Value="PF" />
      <Enumeration Text="Gabon(+241)" Value="GA" />
      <Enumeration Text="Gambia(+220)" Value="GM" />
      <Enumeration Text="Georgia(+995)" Value="GE" />
      <Enumeration Text="Germany(+49)" Value="DE" />
      <Enumeration Text="Ghana(+233)" Value="GH" />
      <Enumeration Text="Gibraltar(+350)" Value="GI" />
      <Enumeration Text="Greece(+30)" Value="GR" />
      <Enumeration Text="Greenland(+299)" Value="GL" />
      <Enumeration Text="Grenada(+1473)" Value="GD" />
      <Enumeration Text="Guadeloupe(+590)" Value="GP" />
      <Enumeration Text="Guam(+1671)" Value="GU" />
      <Enumeration Text="Guatemala(+502)" Value="GT" />
      <Enumeration Text="Guinea(+224)" Value="GN" />
      <Enumeration Text="Guinea-Bissau(+245)" Value="GW" />
      <Enumeration Text="Guyana(+592)" Value="GY" />
      <Enumeration Text="Haiti(+509)" Value="HT" />
      <Enumeration Text="Honduras(+504)" Value="HN" />
      <Enumeration Text="Hong Kong(+852)" Value="HK" />
      <Enumeration Text="Hungary(+36)" Value="HU" />
      <Enumeration Text="Iceland(+354)" Value="IS" />
      <Enumeration Text="India(+91)" Value="IN" />
      <Enumeration Text="Indonesia(+62)" Value="ID" />
      <Enumeration Text="Iran(+98)" Value="IR" />
      <Enumeration Text="Iraq(+964)" Value="IQ" />
      <Enumeration Text="Ireland(+353)" Value="IE" />
      <Enumeration Text="Israel(+972)" Value="IL" />
      <Enumeration Text="Italy(+39)" Value="IT" />
      <Enumeration Text="Jamaica(+1)" Value="JM" />
      <Enumeration Text="Japan(+81)" Value="JP" />
      <Enumeration Text="Jordan(+962)" Value="JO" />
      <Enumeration Text="Kazakhstan(+7)" Value="KZ" />
      <Enumeration Text="Kenya(+254)" Value="KE" />
      <Enumeration Text="Kiribati(+686)" Value="KI" />
      <Enumeration Text="Kuwait(+965)" Value="KW" />
      <Enumeration Text="Kyrgyzstan(+996)" Value="KG" />
      <Enumeration Text="Lao People's Democratic Republic(+856)" Value="LA" />
      <Enumeration Text="Latvia(+371)" Value="LV" />
      <Enumeration Text="Lebanon(+961)" Value="LB" />
      <Enumeration Text="Lesotho(+266)" Value="LS" />
      <Enumeration Text="Liberia(+231)" Value="LR" />
      <Enumeration Text="Libya(+218)" Value="LY" />
      <Enumeration Text="Liechtenstein(+423)" Value="LI" />
      <Enumeration Text="Lithuania(+370)" Value="LT" />
      <Enumeration Text="Luxembourg(+352)" Value="LU" />
      <Enumeration Text="Macao(+853)" Value="MO" />
      <Enumeration Text="North Macedonia, Republic of (+389)" Value="MK" />
      <Enumeration Text="Madagascar(+261)" Value="MG" />
      <Enumeration Text="Malawi(+265)" Value="MW" />
      <Enumeration Text="Malaysia(+60)" Value="MY" />
      <Enumeration Text="Maldives(+960)" Value="MV" />
      <Enumeration Text="Mali(+223)" Value="ML" />
      <Enumeration Text="Malta(+356)" Value="MT" />
      <Enumeration Text="Marshall Islands(+692)" Value="MH" />
      <Enumeration Text="Martinique(+596)" Value="MQ" />
      <Enumeration Text="Mauritania(+222)" Value="MR" />
      <Enumeration Text="Mauritius(+230)" Value="MU" />
      <Enumeration Text="Mexico(+52)" Value="MX" />
      <Enumeration Text="Micronesia(+691)" Value="FM" />
      <Enumeration Text="Moldova, Republic of(+373)" Value="MD" />
      <Enumeration Text="Monaco(+377)" Value="MC" />
      <Enumeration Text="Mongolia(+976)" Value="MN" />
      <Enumeration Text="Montenegro(+382)" Value="ME" />
      <Enumeration Text="Montserrat(+1664)" Value="MS" />
      <Enumeration Text="Morocco(+212)" Value="MA" />
      <Enumeration Text="Mozambique(+258)" Value="MZ" />
      <Enumeration Text="Myanmar(+95)" Value="MM" />
      <Enumeration Text="Namibia(+264)" Value="NA" />
      <Enumeration Text="Nauru(+674)" Value="NR" />
      <Enumeration Text="Nepal(+977)" Value="NP" />
      <Enumeration Text="Netherlands(+31)" Value="NL" />
      <Enumeration Text="New Caledonia(+687)" Value="NC" />
      <Enumeration Text="New Zealand(+64)" Value="NZ" />
      <Enumeration Text="Nicaragua(+505)" Value="NI" />
      <Enumeration Text="Niger(+227)" Value="NE" />
      <Enumeration Text="Nigeria(+234)" Value="NG" />
      <Enumeration Text="Niue(+683)" Value="NU" />
      <Enumeration Text="Korea, Democratic People's Republic of (North Korea)(+850)" Value="KP" />
      <Enumeration Text="Norway(+47)" Value="NO" />
      <Enumeration Text="Oman(+968)" Value="OM" />
      <Enumeration Text="Pakistan(+92)" Value="PK" />
      <Enumeration Text="Palau(+680)" Value="PW" />
      <Enumeration Text="Palestine, State of(+970)" Value="PS" />
      <Enumeration Text="Panama(+507)" Value="PA" />
      <Enumeration Text="Papua New Guinea(+675)" Value="PG" />
      <Enumeration Text="Paraguay(+595)" Value="PY" />
      <Enumeration Text="Peru(+51)" Value="PE" />
      <Enumeration Text="Philippines(+63)" Value="PH" />
      <Enumeration Text="Poland(+48)" Value="PL" />
      <Enumeration Text="Portugal(+351)" Value="PT" />
      <Enumeration Text="Puerto Rico(+1)" Value="PR" />
      <Enumeration Text="Qatar(+974)" Value="QA" />
      <Enumeration Text="Réunion(+262)" Value="RE" />
      <Enumeration Text="Romania(+40)" Value="RO" />
      <Enumeration Text="Russian Federation(+7)" Value="RU" />
      <Enumeration Text="Rwanda(+250)" Value="RW" />
      <Enumeration Text="Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha(+290)" Value="SH" />
      <Enumeration Text="Saint Kitts and Nevis(+1869)" Value="KN" />
      <Enumeration Text="Saint Lucia(+1758)" Value="LC" />
      <Enumeration Text="Saint Pierre and Miquelon(+508)" Value="PM" />
      <Enumeration Text="Saint Vincent and the Grenadines(+1784)" Value="VC" />
      <Enumeration Text="Northern Mariana Islands(CNMI)(+1670)" Value="MP" />
      <Enumeration Text="Samoa(+685)" Value="WS" />
      <Enumeration Text="San Marino(+378)" Value="SM" />
      <Enumeration Text="Sao Tome and Principe(+239)" Value="ST" />
      <Enumeration Text="Saudi Arabia(+966)" Value="SA" />
      <Enumeration Text="Senegal(+221)" Value="SN" />
      <Enumeration Text="Serbia(+381)" Value="RS" />
      <Enumeration Text="Seychelles(+248)" Value="SC" />
      <Enumeration Text="Sierra Leone(+232)" Value="SL" />
      <Enumeration Text="Singapore(+65)" Value="SG" />
      <Enumeration Text="Slovakia(+421)" Value="SK" />
      <Enumeration Text="Slovenia(+386)" Value="SI" />
      <Enumeration Text="Solomon Islands(+677)" Value="SB" />
      <Enumeration Text="Somalia(+252)" Value="SO" />
      <Enumeration Text="South Africa(+27)" Value="ZA" />
      <Enumeration Text="Korea, Republic of(+82)" Value="KR" />
      <Enumeration Text="South Sudan(+211)" Value="SS" />
      <Enumeration Text="Spain(+34)" Value="ES" />
      <Enumeration Text="Sri Lanka(+94)" Value="LK" />
      <Enumeration Text="Sudan(+249)" Value="SD" />
      <Enumeration Text="Suriname(+597)" Value="SR" />
      <Enumeration Text="Swaziland(+268)" Value="SZ" />
      <Enumeration Text="Sweden(+46)" Value="SE" />
      <Enumeration Text="Switzerland(+41)" Value="CH" />
      <Enumeration Text="Syrian Arab Republic(+963)" Value="SY" />
      <Enumeration Text="Taiwan, Province of China(+886)" Value="TW" />
      <Enumeration Text="Tajikistan(+992)" Value="TJ" />
      <Enumeration Text="Tanzania, United Republic of(+255)" Value="TZ" />
      <Enumeration Text="Thailand(+66)" Value="TH" />
      <Enumeration Text="Togo(+228)" Value="TG" />
      <Enumeration Text="Tokelau(+690)" Value="TK" />
      <Enumeration Text="Tonga(+676)" Value="TO" />
      <Enumeration Text="Trinidad and Tobago(+1868)" Value="TT" />
      <Enumeration Text="Tunisia(+216)" Value="TN" />
      <Enumeration Text="Turkey(+90)" Value="TR" />
      <Enumeration Text="Turkmenistan(+993)" Value="TM" />
      <Enumeration Text="Turks and Caicos Islands(+1649)" Value="TC" />
      <Enumeration Text="Tuvalu(+688)" Value="TV" />
      <Enumeration Text="Uganda(+256)" Value="UG" />
      <Enumeration Text="Ukraine(+380)" Value="UA" />
      <Enumeration Text="United Arab Emirates(+971)" Value="AE" />
      <Enumeration Text="United Kingdom(+44)" Value="GB" />
      <Enumeration Text="United States(+1)" Value="US" />
      <Enumeration Text="Virgin Islands, U.S.(+1340)" Value="VI" />
      <Enumeration Text="Uruguay(+598)" Value="UY" />
      <Enumeration Text="Uzbekistan(+998)" Value="UZ" />
      <Enumeration Text="Vanuatu(+678)" Value="VU" />
      <Enumeration Text="Holy See (Vatican City State)(+379)" Value="VA" />
      <Enumeration Text="Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of(+58)" Value="VE" />
      <Enumeration Text="Viet Nam(+84)" Value="VN" />
      <Enumeration Text="Wallis and Futuna(+681)" Value="WF" />
      <Enumeration Text="Yemen(+967)" Value="YE" />
      <Enumeration Text="Zambia(+260)" Value="ZM" />
      <Enumeration Text="Zimbabwe(+263)" Value="ZW" />
    </Restriction>
  </ClaimType>
```

Comment: Please update country code for UAE. I copied from here and later realized Ukraine and UAE have same country codes. Please update it to AE. You can refer this list for more information: https://www.iban.com/country-codes

Comment: Well that's disappointing from MS, thanks I've edited

Comment: Also added a PR to update their github repo